# Linux virtualbox machine ssh from host

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox

I've recently created a CentOS 6.5 Virtualbox machine. (Portable-Virtualbox)

This is currently a replica of the CentOS 6.5 desktop that I use as a file server.

In order to use this Virtualbox CentOS as a testing platform I need to be able to SSH into it to perform some tasks as though it's the desktop.

I have adjusted the network settings through virtual box to the following :

```
Adapter 1 - Attached to NAT

Adapter 2 - Host-only Adapter
            Name: Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #5

            Promiscious mode: Allow All
```

the inet address that I get is 10.0.2.15

when I try to SSH into 10.0.2.15 from PuTTY on the Host machine it doesn't allow me to connect. It just fails with a timeout.

Did I miss a step or set something up incorrectly?

```
UPDATE
```

After tinkering i discovered an issue, I encountered a pop-up box saying

```
"The file "VBoxNetFltNobj.dll" on VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver is needed".
```

i need to find this file

Comment: Try changing adapter option from NAT to bridged. Your IP will be changed as well.

Comment: When I change it to bridged it says that:                              no bridged network adapter is currently selected. under name it says none selected but there are no options in the dropdown box

Comment: Seems like vbox bridged networking driver was not installed successfully for you. Try to reinstall virtualbox.

Comment: I don't want to get too drastic just yet because it was a mission to get virtualbox running in the first place :'D if I don't find a solution then I will definitely reinstall

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that it is Portable-Virtualbox, this is another reason I am not so keen on reinstalling it

Comment: After tinkering i discovered  an issue, I encountered a pop-up box saying "The file "VBoxNetFltNobj.dll" on VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver is needed". i need to find this file

Comment: Have you configured network as shown [here](http://www.vbox.me/)?

Comment: Yeah XD that's exactly the page I followed, please don't tell me it's wrong

Comment: You can't connect directly to the guest's NAT interface from the host. Does the guest's host-only interface have an IP address? Try connecting from the host to that IP.

Comment: It does have an IP address but it looks like the issue is related to the missing driver

Comment: Ok I've re-installed Virtualbox and downloaded the driver and when I start it up I load the driver and I can choose the right network card now but when I do choose the Network card it gives me the can't access the kernel driver error. when I start without the network driver it runs fine... Now it's just getting annoying

Comment: @Trent have you tried to run vbox with administrator rights?

Comment: I have not 0_0 it didn't cross my mind, I will give that a bash